# How to set a colomn(that already exists) to a specific number in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to set a column (which already exists) from a table to a specific number, for example I have a `User` table which has a "PP" column and I want to set up this column to +20 points.

How can I do that?

I'm using phpmyadmin.

Comment: You want to increase the value of column with name "PP" by 20 for all records in table "User" ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can update every row in a table by omitting the `WHERE` clause from an `UPDATE` query.

```
 UPDATE table SET pp = pp + 20
```

will do what you ask. Be careful when you omit `WHERE` clauses. On SELECT queries, you just get too much data back. On `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries you can lose data.